# R studio: "Error in system(command, intern = T) : 'ls' not found"

Tags: formatting, rstudio, file-conversion

I am in the process of using the **GenABEL** package of R studio to convert the output of the Affymetrix Genotyping Console into a .tfam file. This is my code thus far:

```
rm(list = ls())

setwd("C:/U/Is/GD/Affymetrix")

library("GenABEL", lib.loc="C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-211~1.1-X/library")

read.table("Genotyping_results.txt", fill = TRUE)

convert.snp.affymetrix(dir = "C:/U/Is/GD/Affymetrix", map = "Genotyping_results.txt" , outfile ="Genotyping_results.tfam")
```

I am getting the following error: 
**"Error in system(command, intern = T) : 'ls' not found".**
I have a limited understanding of programming and am finding it difficult to understand what is wrong or how I can solve it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned in the comments that you're using Windows. `ls` is not a command on your OS.

`ls` is a command in Linux and in R.

There are many ways to add that command to Windows, like Cygwin.